# Как применить favicon в Markdown (хостинг Github Pages)?

Tags: html, github, github-pages, markdown, favicon

создана страничка посредством https://pages.github.com/

В репозитории имеются лишь два файла index.md и favicon.ico. Как сделать так, чтобы иконка применилась к странице?

Внутри тега head в файле index добавляется `link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"`, чтобы иконка применилась к вкладке страницы, но Markdown игнорирует head.

Html версию того, что генерирует Jekyll, в репозиторий заливать очень не хочется.
Хочу ограничиться лишь md страничками и на крайняк html вставками в самих же md файлах.

Есть вариант, представленный здесь (https://youtu.be/4v-8_JSydgk) и сгенерировать файл _config.yml, но хотелось узнать есть ли еще какой то способ?
Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем то, что вы описываете, но возможно такой вариант тоже подойдет.

Смысл такой: есть markdown файл, который рендерится в html и подставляется в html шаблон из папки `_layouts`. В шаблоне внутри тега `<head></head>` прописывается все что нужно, в том числе указывается фавикон. Также лучше общие куски разных лэйаутов выносить в отдельные подключаемые "подшаблоны", складывать в папку `_includes`, потом в шаблоне лэйаута подключать с помощью "директивы" `{% include head.html %}`.

Я считаю, что отдельные html шаблоны удобнее, чем постоянная вставка одного и того же html кода внутрь markdown страниц.

Структура более-менее минимального проекта:

- `_includes`

  - `head.html`
- `_layouts`

  - `default.html`
- `public`

  - `favicon.ico`
- `index.md`

Файл `index.md`:

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
---

## Header

Some text
```

- `layout` указывает, какой шаблон из папки `_layouts` будет использоваться для отображения страницы (`layout: default` указывать не обязательно, по умолчанию и так будет использован `default`)
- `title` - заголовок страницы, можно подставить в шаблон (например в head.html) через `{{ page.title }}`

---

Файл `default.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  {% include head.html %}

  <body>
      {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Вместо `{{ content }}` тут подставится преобразованное в html тело markdown страницы.

---

Файл head.html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>{{ site.title }} / {{ page.title }} </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/public/favicon.ico">
</head>
```

`site.title` подставится из `_config.yml` (если он есть) из свойства `title`, `page.title` - из front matter страницы (того что в начале файла между тройными отчеркиваниями).

В рабочем виде (возможно потом удалю):

- https://insolor.github.io/test_favicon/ (проект - https://github.com/insolor/test_favicon)

В целом, можно ориентироваться на структуру проектов с нестандартными (для github pages) темами Jekyll, например я изучал проект [Hyde](https://github.com/poole/hyde).